# Smart way to write where col1 = x OR col2 = x on ALL the columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have 100 columns and I want to search for something but I don't know which column to search.

How can I write a loop that:

````
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 'x' OR col2 ='x' OR col3 = 'x' OR .... OR col100 = 'x';
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If numerous and/or variable columns and performance is **NOT** an primary concern.

**Example**

```
 Select *
  From  YourTable A
  Where charindex('X', (Select A.* for xml raw) )>0
```

**EDIT** - To get exact match use quotes in the charindex('`"X"`',...)

**EDIT - To See what is happening**

```
Select RecordString=(Select A.* for xml raw) 
 From  YourTable A
```

Comment: Well thanks it works but I don't understand ``(Select A.* for xml raw)``. I understand that ``A`` is the subquery but why can I not run it separately... ?

Comment: @David It creates an XML Raw string of the RECORD not the data-set.  Thus very important to use the alias.   Just for fun, Select RecordString=(Select A.* for xml raw) from YourTable A

Comment: @David See EDIT

Comment: Okay, so you fit all the columns in one cell and then search for the string, right?

Comment: @David BINGO... not elegant but I've used this in my discovery phase.   AGAIN, if you have a big table, you may want to re-think this  :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `in`:

```
where 'x' in (col1, col2, col3, . . . col100)
```

Note:  You need to list all the columns.  `. . .` is not part of SQL.

Comment: Is it possible to ``cast`` everything in the parentheses at once?

Comment: @David . . . No, but your question is not about casting values.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM table
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP(1) 'YES' 
   FROM 
      (VALUES (col1),(col2),....(col100) ) t(col)
   WHERE CAST(t.col AS ..) = 'x'
) cond(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that the method with a 100x OR is likely best for performance.

You can build the query in Excel or use dynamic sql to build the string.